# Local Coordinate defined as function?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I'm confused about this definition in chapter one of Griffith's Introduction to Algebraic Curves:

> Suppose C is a compact Riemann Surface, with $f\in K(C), p\in C.$ Select a local coordinate $z$ in a neighborhood of the point $p$ such that $z(p)=0.$ Then in a neighborhood of $p$ $$f=z^{\nu}h(z),$$ where $h(z)$ is a holomorphic function, $h(0)\neq 0$, and $\nu\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I was wondering what it means for $z(p)$ to be equal to zero, since $z$ is a local coordinate. What does this mean? Does this mean that $z$ is a function? How do we use a local coordinate as a function in this way?

Comment: At first $z$ is a function holomorphic from a neighborhood of $p\in C$ to a neighborhood of $0\in \Bbb{C}$. Later you'll show that $z$ can be chosen to be meromorphic on the whole of $C$ (ie. $z\in K(C)$). $h$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of $0\in \Bbb{C}$, when $z\in K(C)$ then the analytic continuation of $h$ exists on almost every curve not passing by finitely many branch points (if every $h=h_f$ extends meromorphically to the Riemann sphere then $K(C)=\Bbb{C}(z)$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the local coordinate $z$ is really a homeomorphism $z : U \to \mathbb{C}$, going from a small piece of the Riemann surface $C$ to some open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. By possibly translating $z(U) \subset \mathbb{C}$, we can assume that $z(p) = 0 \in \mathbb{C}$, i.e. z maps $p$ to the origin. That way, the chart $(U, z)$ is "centered" around $p$.

The atlas of such charts $\{(U, z)\}$ comes with the initial data of a Riemann surface.

Comment: The book also says $f=z^{\nu}h(z)$, so what does $z$ mean in this context?

Comment: The $z$ in the equation $f = z^\nu h(z)$ is the same one as my answer. That is, $z$ is a function from $U \to \mathbb{C}$, $h$ is holomorphic on $z(U)$, etc.